# unix: files starting with - wildcard

Tags: shell, unix

I want to rm or cp a bunch of files with common extensions, some of them start with a `-` and so unix complains about unknown options. What can I do?

`rm *csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`man rm`:

```
To remove a file whose name starts with a '-', for example '-foo', 
use one of these commands:

       rm -- -foo

       rm ./-foo
```

So:

```
$ touch -- -test test
$ rm -- *test
rm: remove regular empty file 'test'? y
rm: remove regular empty file '-test'? y
$
```

Answer (score -1):

Also, quoting works to inhibit globbing if there's, say, a literal asterisk in the name:

```
rm "*cvs"
```

Sometimes it might be useful to use the *interactive* option and confirm the file you want to delete:

```
rm -i -- *
```

This is handy if filenames have characters hard to type on your keyboard.

Comment: @JamesBrown Well, what do you expect? You did not create a file named `*test` with a literal asterisk, you can't remove it.